# How to avoid a retain cycle on my custom dependency injection tool?

Tags: swift, dependency-injection, property-wrapper

I have created a custom `propertyWrapper` to inject my dependencies in code so when testing the code, I can pass a mock in place using the `WritableKeyPath` link to the object in memory.

This is how I would use it in production code. It is very convenient as I don't need to pass the object inside an initializer.

```swift
@Injected(\.child) var child
```

And this is how I would use it in my unit tests to pass the mock in place of the `WritableKeyPath`.

```swift
let parentMock = ParentMock()
InjectedDependency[\.parent] = parentMock
```

The thing is that in some part of the code where I am trying to use it, there seems to be ghost objects that are being created when the `Child` class would need to have access to the `Parent` class in a cycle. When I am making a look up and play with it in the Playground, I could have noticed that there are two objects created when linked to each others, and only one deallocation for each of them instead of two when setting the variable to `nil`.

How can I update my `@propertyWrapper` or what could be improved on this solution to make it work as expected? How come two objects are created instead of them making a references to the objects in memory?

So the use in code of this custom dependency injection tool is set below.
I have implemented the classic way with a `weak var parent: Parent?` to deallocate the object in memory with no issue to showcase what I was expected.

```swift
protocol ParentProtocol {}
class Parent: ParentProtocol {

  //var child: Child?
  @Injected(\.child) var child

  init() { print(" Allocating Parent in memory") }
  deinit { print ("♻️ Deallocating Parent from memory") }
}

protocol ChildProtocol {}
class Child: ChildProtocol {

  //weak var parent: Parent?
  @Injected(\.parent) var parent

  init() { print(" Allocating Child in memory") }
  deinit { print("♻️ Deallocating Child from memory") }
}

var mary: Parent? = Parent()
var tom: Child? = Child()

mary?.child = tom!
tom?.parent = mary!

// When settings the Parent and Child to nil,
// both are expected to be deallocating.
mary = .none
tom = .none
```

This is the response in the log when using the custom dependency injection solution.

```swift
 Allocating Parent in memory
 Allocating Child in memory
 Allocating Child in memory // Does not appear when using the weak reference. 
♻️ Deallocating Child from memory
 Allocating Parent in memory // Does not appear when using the weak reference. 
♻️ Deallocating Parent from memory
```

This is the implementation of my custom `PropertyWrapper` to handle the dependency injection following the keys of the `Parent` and the `Child` for the example of use.

```swift
// The key protocol for the @propertyWrapper initialization.
protocol InjectedKeyProtocol {
  associatedtype Value
  static var currentValue: Self.Value { get set }
}

// The main dependency injection custom tool.
@propertyWrapper
struct Injected<T> {

    private let keyPath: WritableKeyPath<InjectedDependency, T>

    var wrappedValue: T {
        get { InjectedDependency[keyPath] }
        set { InjectedDependency[keyPath] = newValue }
    }

    init(_ keyPath: WritableKeyPath<InjectedDependency, T>) {
        self.keyPath = keyPath
    }
}

// The custom tool to use in unit tests to implement the mock
// within the associated WritableKeyPath.
struct InjectedDependency {

    private static var current = InjectedDependency()

    static subscript<K>(key: K.Type) -> K.Value where K: InjectedKeyProtocol {
        get { key.currentValue }
        set { key.currentValue = newValue }
    }

    static subscript<T>(_ keyPath: WritableKeyPath<InjectedDependency, T>) -> T {
        get { current[keyPath: keyPath] }
        set { current[keyPath: keyPath] = newValue }
    }
}

// The Parent and Child keys to access the object in memory.
extension InjectedDependency {
  var parent: ParentProtocol {
    get { Self[ParentKey.self] }
    set { Self[ParentKey.self] = newValue }
  }

  var child: ChildProtocol {
    get { Self[ChildKey.self] }
    set { Self[ChildKey.self] = newValue }
  }
}

// The instantiation of the value linked to the key.
struct ParentKey: InjectedKeyProtocol {
    static var currentValue: ParentProtocol = Parent()
}

struct ChildKey: InjectedKeyProtocol {
    static var currentValue: ChildProtocol = Child()
}
```

Comment: Playgrounds aren’t suitable for running experiments about memory ownership like this. The playground itself makes strong references to objects for the purpose of displaying them. Try this in a regular, non-playground stand-alone swift file, and run that

Comment: Also, don’t you have a strong reference cycle between parent and child? You still need to use a weak reference, even with your property wrapper. That can be tricky, because `weak` isn’t a type, it’s a property modified, but you can make yourself a box like `struct Weak<T: AnyObject> { let wrapped: T }`, and then define your parent as `@Injected(\.parent) var parent: Weak<Parent>`

Comment: @Alexander I did try on a stand-alone swift file within a Command Line Tool project and it does exactly the same thing. Two ghosts objects are created. As for your second answer, I did not manage to make your tool working. Could you post a StackOverflow answer with a working response.

Comment: Not really, I couldn't get these snippets to compile to begin with (`@Injected(\.child) var child` is invalid without a type annotation, and IDK what type it should be), but I would love to help work through it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many changes, so just compare - in general we need to think about reference counting, ie. who keeps references... and so it works only for reference-types.

Tested with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4

```
protocol ParentProtocol: AnyObject {}
class Parent: ParentProtocol {

  //var child: Child?
  @Injected(\.child) var child

  init() { print(" Allocating Parent in memory") }
  deinit { print ("♻️ Deallocating Parent from memory") }
}

protocol ChildProtocol: AnyObject {}
class Child: ChildProtocol {

  //weak var parent: Parent?
  @Injected(\.parent) var parent

  init() { print(" Allocating Child in memory") }
  deinit { print("♻️ Deallocating Child from memory") }
}

protocol InjectedKeyProtocol {
  associatedtype Value
  static var currentValue: Self.Value? { get set }
}

// The main dependency injection custom tool.
@propertyWrapper
struct Injected<T> {

    private let keyPath: WritableKeyPath<InjectedDependency, T?>

    var wrappedValue: T? {
        get { InjectedDependency[keyPath] }
        set { InjectedDependency[keyPath] = newValue }
    }

    init(_ keyPath: WritableKeyPath<InjectedDependency, T?>) {
        self.keyPath = keyPath
    }
}

// The custom tool to use in unit tests to implement the mock
// within the associated WritableKeyPath.
struct InjectedDependency {

    private static var current = InjectedDependency()

    static subscript<K>(key: K.Type) -> K.Value? where K: InjectedKeyProtocol {
        get { key.currentValue }
        set { key.currentValue = newValue }
    }

    static subscript<T>(_ keyPath: WritableKeyPath<InjectedDependency, T?>) -> T? {
        get { current[keyPath: keyPath] }
        set { current[keyPath: keyPath] = newValue }
    }
}

// The Parent and Child keys to access the object in memory.
extension InjectedDependency {
  var parent: ParentProtocol? {
    get { Self[ParentKey.self] }
    set { Self[ParentKey.self] = newValue }
  }

  var child: ChildProtocol? {
    get { Self[ChildKey.self] }
    set { Self[ChildKey.self] = newValue }
  }
}

// The instantiation of the value linked to the key.
struct ParentKey: InjectedKeyProtocol {
    static weak var currentValue: ParentProtocol?
}

struct ChildKey: InjectedKeyProtocol {
    static weak var currentValue: ChildProtocol?
}
```

Output for test code:

[image]

[Complete test module in project is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestWeirdReferenceInjector.swift)